# creating dictionary using 'for' expression in Python

Tags: python, dictionary

Why only 2 elements are generated for dict?

## Python

Why running:

```
dd = {10*i: j for i in (4,5) for j in (7,9)}
print (dd)
```

Returns:

```
{40: 9, 50: 9}
```

Why not: ??

```
{40: 9, 50: 9, 50: 7, 40: 7}
```

At the same time running:

```
dd = {10*i + j: j for i in (4,5) for j in (7,9)}
print (dd)
```

Returns:

```
{49: 9, 59: 9, 57: 7, 47: 7}
```

Comment: Dictionaries can't have two of the same key.

Answer (score 3):

That's actually not how dictionaries work.

Dictionaries in python are key-value pairs. That means that each key has one value associated with it. If at any time we try to assign a different value to the same key, the value is overwritten.

```
>>> a = { 1: 10, 2: 20 }
>>> a[1] = 40
>>> a
{ 1: 40, 2: 20 }
```